# Google App Engine - Adding Methods to subclasses of db.model

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I would like to know if I can add methods to a subclass of db.model. For example:

```
class Session(db.model):
    sessionId = db.StringProperty()
    # More Properties

    def refreshSession(self):
        #do some work
        self.put()
```

Implementation:

```
s = Session()
s.refreshSession()
```

Is this recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the typical way to add behavior to model objects.  Why wouldn't you do it this way?

Comment: It made sense in my head as well, but none of the Google documentation does this - so I was curious.

Comment: Calling `put` in your method is usually a bad design decision, though, since it makes it impossible for the caller to do batch operations.

Comment: I am facing problem while defining a class function. Did either of you try that ?